# MFC application that uses Serial Ports

Tags: c++, mfc, serial-port

For my thesis I'm given an application written in visual c++ and using MFC that receives gps data (NMEA 183 (RMC)), the data is received from UDP and/or a Serial port (COM port) (they have to work separatly or together). The UDP part of the application is done and its working (written by another student before me), so I have to finish the Serial port part, but here comes my problem, it turns out that MFC does not support COM ports or at least doesn't have a class for serial ports, I found some serial port implementation on the internet: [LINK](http://www.naughter.com/serialport.html), but I dont know how to integrate it and make it work, it turns out that the UDP part is working like an event triggering mechanism using virtual function **CAsyncSocket::OnReceive**. I was wondering if its posible to make anything similar to this working with Serial Ports?

Thank you for your help.
Best Regards.

Comment: MFC just doesn't pretend to wrap the *entire* winapi.  There's fairly little point to it, the winapi functions for serial ports are already pretty high-level and hide a lot of the implementation details.  Boost's asio wraps it, imperfectly because it needs to work on any operating system, that ship has probably already sailed.  You'll have to wrap it yourself.  Pretty decent student exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program is a GUI then it is a good idea to run the serial port code in a separate worker thread.  ReadFile can take a long time to get serial data and this would block the GUI message processing if it was done in the main thread. To provide notification events from the serial thread to the main (GUI) thread you can use PostMessage with a user-defined message. An example of doing this is at
http://vcfaq.mvps.org/mfc/12.htm

Comment: There are better ways to do it than a background thread (OVERLAPPED read with a completion routine) but those probably don't play well with the MFC message dispatch loop (you have to use an alertable wait when fetching messages, I don't know that MFC does).  So this is a reasonable approach.

Comment: ScottMcP-MVP Thank you, that did the trick.
@BenVoigt I tried overlapped read, but it was making the code more complicated with nothing much to offer for my case. I just did a basic ReadFile with a timeout.